# Changing a pages layout via javascript, moving forward, then clicking BACK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have started to design in allowing customers to either login to our booking process, or enter their details fresh into a form. They get two options when the page loads.

If the user logs in, they enter an email and password, and if successful it will display the form with all their details pre-populated ready for submission.

The customer then goes to the payment page. If they click BACK, the previous page presents them with the original 2 options again: Login or fill out the form (which is now hidden as it was to begin with).

What is the best way to remember the UI the user saw before they submitted a form to leave a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using HTML5 Web Storage.  If you set a storage unit with the UI that is being displayed you should be able to use it to determine which UI should be displayed when it goes back using something like this:

```
if (localStorage.uiNum) {
  //code handling which UI should be displayed
}
else {
  //code displaying the default option for when no storage info is found
}
```

Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) with more information!  Make sure you clear the storage when you are done so the next time they access the page they are taken to the default UI.

Comment: You sir... have shown me something I have never seen before, and it works! Thank you.